# Debian Buster: Tracker GUI (tracker-needle) missing

Tags: debian, gui, tracker

After upgrading from [Debian Stretch](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch) to [Buster](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster) I found that [Tracker desktop search GUI (tracker-needle)](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/tracker-gui) was missing. How can I get it back?

Please, don't suggest installing [Recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/). I used to use it quite a while but its indexer was resource hog and I switched to [Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracker no longer provides its own search interface; instead, GNOME applications such as Documents and Music will use its indexes for their search features. You can also search for file contents from GNOME Shell: open the “Activities” view and type your search query.

See [the Tracker documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/GettingStarted) for details.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I use [Xfce](https://www.xfce.org/). According to [this comment](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14481#c1) Tracker Catfish integration should work but for some reason it does not work for me. Maybe I must use Tracker CLI from now on...